# merging objects delete initial keys

Tags: javascript, object, spread

I have two objects obj1 & obj2.

when I merge with:

```js
const obj1 = {
  error_to_retrieve: "teste",
  error_to_search_customer: "",
  error_to_sync_timezone: "",
  error_to_update_avatar: "",
  error_to_update_profile: "",
  error_to_validate_customer_token: "",
  expired_session: "",
  invalid_token: "",
  invalid_token_text: ""
}

const obj2 = {
  error_to_retrieve: "test",
  error_to_search_customer: "test",
  error_to_sync_timezone: "test",
  error_to_update_avatar: "test",
  error_to_validate_customer_token: "test",
  expired_session: "test",
  invalid_token: "test",
  invalid_token_text: "test"
}


const obj3 = {...obj1, ...obj2};

console.log(obj3);
```

I get the full obj2, and it dont have the key error_to_update_profile.

How I maintain the key of the first object that my second dont have?

Comment: `error_to_update_profile.` It does for me.   ps, your missing comma's on your obj1 & obj2

Comment: I ran it in my browser's console and I have the `error_to_update_profil` key

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to check whether your final objects has the property key `error_to_update_profile`. The funtion returns `true` which is prove that the merge worked perfectly fine as intended.

```js
const obj1 = {
  error_to_retrieve: "teste",
  error_to_search_customer: "",
  error_to_sync_timezone: "",
  error_to_update_avatar: "",
  error_to_update_profile: "",
  error_to_validate_customer_token: "",
  expired_session: "",
  invalid_token: "",
  invalid_token_text: ""
};

const obj2 = {
  error_to_retrieve: "test",
  error_to_search_customer: "test",
  error_to_sync_timezone: "test",
  error_to_update_avatar: "test",
  error_to_validate_customer_token: "test",
  expired_session: "test",
  invalid_token: "test",
  invalid_token_text: "test"
};

const obj3 = { ...obj1, ...obj2 };

console.log(obj3.hasOwnProperty("error_to_update_profile"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the order of what to write, i.e. whatever you put last will overwrite all previous entries `{ ...obj2, ...obj1 }` → `obj1` will overwrite `obj2` if there are duplicate keys

Comment: See [Spread in object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals)